# Weird random value as default interval handler parameter

Tags: javascript, firefox, setinterval

Just came across this. It's not affecting anything really but i'm wondering why it's happening.

If I run the following code in firefox with firebug on:

```
setInterval(function(param) 
     {
        console.log("param is %o",param)
     },500);
```

param seems to be assigned a vaguely random value:

```
   param is -2
    param is -1
    param is -2
    param is 1
    param is -1
    param is 6
    param is -1
    param is 0
    param is -2
    param is 2
    param is 0
    param is 2
    param is 0
    param is 0
    param is 0
[..]
    param is 0
    param is 0
    param is 0
    param is 0
    param is 0
    param is 0
    param is 0
    param is 911
    param is 0
    param is 0
    param is 0
    param is -1
```

I do appreciate that I'm not passing any argument to setInterval to pass on to the function, but why does javascript chooses to pass this random number ?

I would have expected undefined or something like that...

Cheers

p.s. Haven't tested in other browsers

Comment: By the way, you can test this more simply like this: `setInterval(console.log, 500)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be dependent upon Firefox's CPU usage.

I would guess that it's the delay from when the callback should have been called.

**EDIT**: [I was right](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval#Callback_arguments).  It's the number of milliseconds late the callback was called.

Comment: Well done. Makes sense. 
Seems to be always added as an additional parameter.So if 2 arguments as passed, that value is the third one..

Comment: yeah, I was just on that page too

Answer (score 0):

it's an interval ID automatically set by `window.setInterval`.  if you store the result, you can clear the interval later (to stop it)

```
var intID = window.setInterval( function(){ alert("I'm annoying!"); }, 10000 );

// this will kill it before it annoys you, :D
window.clearInterval( intID );
```

this is also the case with `window.setTimeout`:

```
var timeID = window.setTimeout( function(){ alert("I'm annoying!"); }, 10000 );

// this will kill it before it annoys you, :D
window.clearTimeout( timeID );
```

Comment: You're misunderstanding his question.  He's not asking what `setInterval` returns; he's asking what it passes to the callback.

Comment: yeah, my bad, just realized this.  that is weird.

Comment: this is the wrong answer, but maybe somebody doesn't know this either, so whatevs